# iOS - is this declaration inside a class correct?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Suppose I am creating a subclass of UITextView named for example, myTextView. I will make that class its own delegate. So, I need to implement the delegates methods like

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
```

Should I declare this method like that or like this?

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(myTextView *)textView {
```

it appears to me like recursive, because I am inside myTextView class, defining a delegate that is referring itself...

what is the correct approach? thanks.

Comment: Either will work (assuming that `myTextView` is the derived class name).  But the first is customary.  (BTW, by convention, class names in Objective-C should begin with an upper-case character.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for clarification is better to implement the methods like are defined in the protocol:

```
 - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

If you implement the protocol methods with your custom class type or whatever class type, the methods will still get called because there is not type check performed. The parameter will be actually your custom subclass. Anyway, and again for clarification, I suggest to have an inner cast if you want to deal with the ivars of your custom subclass:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    MyTextView * myTextView = (MyTextView *)textView;
    ...
}
```

Comment: "In other case, they will not get called because your class won't conform the protocol." is not true, because `respondsToSelector:` is used for that check - and it doesn't care about types, only method names.

Comment: H2CO3, you're right, it's not performing any type checking. Anyway, it's worth to use the protocol declaration in order to not to lead to confusion (and will be prone to errors with no warnings, at least by default) because you'll get a UITextView as a parameter, not your subclass with your declared ivars.

Comment: @atxe in this case, please edit your answer, it's simply **false** what you wrote.

Comment: @atxe and anyways, it's just a matter of declaration - the passed-in object will still be of the custom class, and *not* `UITextField`, regardless of as what type it is passed in/cast to.

Comment: @atxe I'm not tough, your answer is perfect now.